# Airflow GitHub Authentication Failing

Tags: github, oauth, airflow, authlib, flask-oauthlib

I have a working instance of Airflow already.  I am now trying to set up Airflow with GitHub Enterprise Authentication.  There is not much available as far as documentation and I did not find any good examples online so I am having some trouble.  The Airflow instance works fine when I have authentication set to false, but when I try to turn on the authentication and start up the Airflow instance I get the following error 
`CRITICAL - Cannot import authentication module airflow.contrib.auth.backends.github_enterprise_auth. Please correct your authentication backend or disable authentication: No module named 'flask_oauthlib'`

The relevant portion of the `airflow.cfg` file is as follows:

```
[webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.github_enterprise_auth

[github_enterprise]
api_rev = v3
host = github.com
# From your OAuth app
client_id = CLIENT_ID_CODE
client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET_CODE
oauth_callback_route = /oauth/callback
# airflow team in github
# allowed_teams =
```

I tried completely recreating my virtual Python environment and pip installing Flask_OAuthlib but still no luck.

Is there anyone who knows how to do this and could explain to me how to get this working.

[This](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html#github-enterprise-ghe-authentication) is the only documentation I could find on the subject and I am still not clear.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to set up airflow with github authentication? Does [this github plug-in](https://github.com/airflow-plugins/github_plugin) help at all?

Comment: That link does not seem to have what I am looking for.  See my edit to the original question, I put a link to the only documentation I could find to show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get the `flask_oauthlib` module. I am creating Airflow through a Docker instance and I the correct modules installed in my Python virtual environment, but I didn't have the correct `pip install` statement in my Dockerfile.